# Silverlight - Waiting for asynchronous call to finish before returning from a method

Tags: multithreading, silverlight, wcf

I have a Silverlight application that uses WCF services and also uses the Wintellect Power Threading library to ensure logic executes fully before the application continues.  This is achieved by calling back to the application using delegates so it can continue after the service call has completely finished.

I wish to achieve the same thing in another part of my application but without the use of callbacks e.g. call method that uses WCF service to say load an object from the database, wait for this to return and then return the Id of the object from the original method called.

The only way I could see to do this was to carry out the call to the WCF service in a helper library which loads the object on a different thread and the original method would keep checking the helper library (using static variables) to wait for it to complete and then return it.

Is this the best way to achieve this functionality?  If so here are details of my implementation which is not working correctly.

```
public class MyHelper
{

    private static Thread _thread;
    private static User _loadedObject;        

    public static GetUser()
    {
        return _loadedObject;
    }

    public static void LoadObject(int userId)
    {
        _loadedObject = null;
        ParameterizedThreadStart ts = new ParameterizedThreadStart(DoWork);           
        _thread = new Thread(ts);
        _thread.Start(userId);

    }

    private static void DoWork(object parameter)
    {            
        var ae = new AsyncEnumerator();
        ae.BeginExecute(DoWorkWorker(ae, Convert.ToInt32(parameter)), ae.EndExecute);    
    }

    private static IEnumerator<Int32> DoWorkWorker(AsyncEnumerator ae, int userId)
    {
        // Create a service using a helper method
        var service = ServiceHelper.GetService<IUserServiceAsync>();
        service.BeginGetUserById(userId, ae.End(), null);
        yield return 1;

        _loadedObject = service.EndGetUserById(ae.DequeueAsyncResult());
        _thread.Abort();
    }
}
```

My method then is:

```
public int GetUser(int userId)
{
    MyHelper.LoadObject(userId);
    User user = MyHelper.GetUser();
    while (user == null)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        user = MyHelper.GetUser();
    }
    return user.Id;
 }
```

The call to the get the user is executed on a different thread in the helper method but never returns.  Perhaps this is due to the yield and the calling method sleeping.  I have checked the call to get the user is on a different thread so I think everything should be kept separate,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole construct you are using does not match current best practices of Silverlight. In Silverlight your data access methods (via WebServices of course) are executed asynchronously. You should not design around that, but adapt your design accordingly.

However calling services sequentially (which is different than synchonously) can be valid in some scenarios. In [this blog post](http://www.hightech.ir/SeeSharp/wpf-application-with-caliburn-part-four) I have shown how to achieve this by subscribing the Completed event of the remote call and block the UI in the meantime, with which the workflow looks and feels like normal async calls.

Comment: I agree and my application follows the best practices.  This question was experimenting and breaking from those practices.  This question is part of a scenario where I wanted to call a method which in order to calculate its result had to call a number of methods which all could could services asynchronously and then return a computed value.  After the callee had got this value it could then have to optionally execute another method in the same vain and so on. I was looking at ways to code this scenario as simply as possible given the number of callbacks/events to handle.

Answer (score 1):

I believe calls to the server from Silverlight apps use events that fire on the UI thread; I think that's part of the Silverlight host environment in the browser and can't be worked around.  So trying to call back to the server from another thread is never going to end well.  If you are waiting in program code in the UI thread, your never going to get the call result events from your WCF calls.

You **can** simulate a synchronous call from a non-UI thread with a callback on the UI thread, but that is probably not what you want.  It's better to bite the bullet and make your program logic work with the async calls Silverlight gives you.

Answer (score 1):

If you code against the Interface created for your service reference you can call the `Begin` and `End` methods 'synchronously' for each one of your service calls, we then pass in an `Action<T>` to execute after the `End` methods has completed. Take note that you have to do this from a dispatcher. This is very close to making a synchronous call as the code to run after the call is still written where the call is made, and it executes after the service call is completed. It does however involve creating wrapper methods but we also worked around that by hiding our wrappers and generating them automatically. Seems like a lot of work but isn't, and ends up being more elegant than all the event handlers etc. Let me know if you need more info on this pattern